# Use a Resultset as Table (TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say, I have the following:

```
WITH    T1 as (select xxx as MYALIAS FROM T)
        T2 as (select yyy from T1)

SELECT  T2.ID,
        MAX(MYALIAS) AS MAX_ALIAS,      
        T.AN_ALIAS

FROM   T2

WHERE  MAX_ALIAS <> T.AN_ALIAS 
GROUP  BY T2.ID, T.AN_ALIAS
```

Let's imagine the result as a table named `MY_RESULT_TABLE`.

I need to MY_RESULT_TABLE join some other columns.
I need to obtain 
`TEMP_TABLE = MY_RESULT_TABLE + SOME JOINS`.

The question is how can I use this MY_RESULT_TABLE?

I tried to do 
`WITH MY_RESULT_TABLE AS (the code above)`... didn't work...

**EDIT**
My other problem is that I need to insert into MY_TABLE some values from an select from MY_RESULT_TABLE...

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_TO_INSERT ...
SELECT a b c FROM MY_RESULT_TABLE
```

Comment: *didn't work* as in ..? Could you show the exact code you tried?

Comment: I surrounded all the code above `WITH MY_RESULT_TABLE AS ( WITH T1...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work as you've detailed, just remember to separate each CTE with a comma.

**Edit** You can use CTE's for INSERTs and UPDATEs as well. Updated for insert.

```
;
WITH T1 AS 
(
    SELECT xxx 
    AS MYALIAS FROM T
),
T2 AS 
(
    SELECT yyy 
    FROM T1
),
MY_RESULT_TABLE AS 
(
    SELECT  T2.ID,
            MAX(MYALIAS) AS MAX_ALIAS,      
            T.AN_ALIAS
    FROM   T2
    WHERE  MAX_ALIAS <> T.AN_ALIAS 
    GROUP  BY T2.ID, T.AN_ALIAS

)
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_TO_INSERT(col1, col2, col3, ...)
    SELECT ID, MAX_ALIAS, xyz.OtherColumnsHere
        FROM MY_RESULT_TABLE
        INNER JOIN xyz on ...
```

Comment: My problem is that I need to `INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_TO_INSERT
SELECT * FROM MY_RESULT_TABLE` and this apparently does not work with common table expressions... (

Comment: @serhio CTEs work for inserts and updates as well - `WITH CTE AS (...) INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM CTE`. I've updated

Comment: how about "A CTE must be followed by a **single** SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns. "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: @serhio: What is confusing you? `INSERT  INTO ... SELECT ...` is a *single* statement.